# Push failed: Could not get a logplex token for this app

Tags: integration, heroku, github

I am trying to follow the SFDC Integration Workbook. 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_workbook/integration_workbook.pdf

I got stuck on Tutorial #1 Step: 4:
To deploy the local code to Heroku, execute the following command:
git push heroku master

I get this error:

> !     Push failed: Could not get a logplex token for this app. Please
>   try the request again.
>        !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide Request ID b6b5a577-2056- 4956-addb-8649abfaef2d.
>
> To git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git
>        ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>       error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git

I have worked with Rails+Heroku, but this Tutorial uses Java Spring MVC framework...any idea of what is happening?

For some reason my app seams to be created...

```
$ heroku info
=== young-sierra-3666
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git
Owner Email:   lutgardo21@gmail.com
Region:        us
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://young-sierra-3666.herokuapp.com/
```

But does not appears on Heroku Dashboard

Comment: What command provokes the error? `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Can you try again?  I think it's possible that you got lucky and did this during a Logplex service issue: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/667

Answer (score 0):

That was it James! There was a Logplex service issue: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/667
It is now resolved and I was able to deploy. 
Thanks